# How to retrieve unnamed columns after a groupby and unstack?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, multi-index

I have a dataset of events with a `date` column which I need to display in a weekly plot and do some more data processing afterwards. After some googling I found `pd.Grouper(freq="W")` so I am using that to group the events by week and display them. My problem is that after doing the `groupby` and `ungroup` I end up with a data frame where there is an unnamed column that I am unable to refer to except using `iloc`. This is an issue because in later plots I am grouping by other columns so I need a way to refer to this column by name, not iloc.

Here's a reproducible example of my dataset:

```
from datetime import datetime
from faker import Faker

fake = Faker()

start_date = datetime(2023, 1, 1)
end_date = datetime(2023, 2, 1)

# Generate data frame of 30 random dates in January 2023
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {"date": [fake.date_time_between(start_date=start_date, end_date=end_date) for i in range(30)],
     "dummy": [1 for i in range(30)]})  # There's probably a better way of counting than this

grouper = df.set_index("date").groupby([pd.Grouper(freq="W"), 'dummy'])
result = grouper['dummy'].count().unstack('dummy').fillna(0)
```

The `result` data frame that I get has weird indexes/columns that I am unable to navigate:

```
>>> print(result)
dummy       1
date         
2023-01-01  1
2023-01-08  3
2023-01-15  4
2023-01-22  9
2023-01-29  8
2023-02-05  5
```

```
>>> print(result.columns)
Int64Index([1], dtype='int64', name='dummy')
```

Then only column here is `dummy`, but even after `result.dummy` I get an `AttributeError`

I've also tried `result.reset_index()`:

```
dummy       date  1
0     2023-01-01  1
1     2023-01-08  3
2     2023-01-15  4
3     2023-01-22  9
4     2023-01-29  8
5     2023-02-05  5
```

But for this data frame I can only get the `date` column - the counts column named "1" cannot be accessed using `result.reset_index()["1"]` as I get an `AttributeError`

I am completely perplexed by what is going on here, pandas is really powerful but sometimes I find it incredibly unintuitive. I've checked several pages of the docs and checked if there's another index level (there isn't). Can someone who's better at pandas help me out here?

I just want a way to convert the grouped data frame into something like this:

```
            date  counts
0     2023-01-01       1
1     2023-01-08       3
2     2023-01-15       4
3     2023-01-22       9
4     2023-01-29       8
5     2023-02-05       5
```

Where `date` and `counts` are columns and there is an unnamed index

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can solve this by simply doing:

```
from datetime import datetime
from faker import Faker

fake = Faker()

start_date = datetime(2023, 1, 1)
end_date = datetime(2023, 2, 1)

# Generate data frame of 30 random dates in January 2023
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {"date": [fake.date_time_between(start_date=start_date, end_date=end_date) for i in range(30)],
     "dummy": [1 for i in range(30)]})  # There's probably a better way of counting than this

result = df.groupby([pd.Grouper(freq="W", key='date'), 'dummy'], squeeze=True)['dummy'].count()
result = result.reset_index(name='counts')
result = result.drop(['dummy'], axis = 1)
```

which gives

```
        date   counts
0 2023-01-01          3
1 2023-01-08          7
2 2023-01-15          5
3 2023-01-22          5
4 2023-01-29          8
5 2023-02-05          2
```

Comment: If you wan't to have OPs exact expected output, you don't need 'dummy' in the Grouper.

Comment: @Franciska I reckoned adding ```result = result.drop(['dummy'], axis = 1)``` was maybe self-evident....but sure!

Comment: I can't believe the answer was so simple, thanks a lot!